# Creating a simple scripting language in C#

Tags: c#, scripting

I need to create a very simple scripting language, as an evolution of a macro language (where placeholders were present and were exchanged for the realdata) which is based essentially on statements that need to be executed in order. I need to support nesting of statements and maybe possibly if conditions.

I think I need a parser to properly detect the statements

For example one statement could be:

## Input("Message"=#Clipboard())

In this case, I would need to execute the #Clipboard() statement first and then the #Input.

Any suggestion of what's the approach for it? I guess I need to contruct a tree and execute it.
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx .

Comment: Who is the end user of the macro Language?

Comment: What about embedding another language within the c#. Is the emphasis on allowing none coding savvied people to run simple scripts or is it running code on the fly?

Comment: The end user is not technically savvy. I need to create a simple high level language with very basic functionalities. I don't want to user to have to write C# code or compile it on the fly. Basically it's a matter of creating a series of statements and execute them. The problem is with statement nesting.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215010/howto-c-sharp-string-to-sql-full-text-catalog-search/3215216#3215216):

Basically, you parse your string using [Postfix Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Also, if you are going to use something more complex, look into building a Recursive Descent Parser.  [Eric White's blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/building-a-simple-recursive-descent-parser-continued) has a great set of articles on the topic.